# get all of document type umbraco with razor

Tags: list, razor, document, umbraco

I have a document type of "info" I also have some custom properites.

infoTitle
infoSummary
infoBody

I want to retrieve all the documents of document type "info" and output the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This simple razor macro should accomplish what you desire:

```
@{
    // Get root node:
    var root = Model.AncestorOrSelf();

    // Get all descendants, filter by type:
    var nodes = root.Descendants("info");

    // Loop through the filtered nodes, displaying the properties:
    <ul>
    @foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        <li>
            <h2>@node.infoTitle</h2>
            <div>@node.infoSummary</div>
            <div>@node.infoBody</div>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```